# Swift 4 function returning 0 for multiple return values

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have been searching around but couldn't find a solution. can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.
 here is my function code: in my database I have hour=5 as Int and Minute=45 as Int
but when I print, the values of the function prints 0,0

```
var docRefF : DocumentReference!

func getTime()-> (Int, Int){
    var FHour = Int()
    var FMinute = Int()

    docRefF = Firestore.firestore().document("sampleTime/worktime")
    dataListener =  docRefF.addSnapshotListener { (docSnapshot, error) in
        guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else { return }

        let data = docSnapshot.data()
        let Hour:Int = data["Hour"]! as! Int
        let Minute: Int = data["Minute"]! as! Int

        FHour = Hour
        FMinute = Minute
    }

    return (FHour, FMinute)
}
let time = getTime()
print("\(time.0),\(time.1)" )
 //printed 0,0
```

Comment: Do some research on the term "asynchronous" and read the documentation for Firestore/Firebase snapshot listeners and completion handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly its issue of **asynchronous** execution. Use *** function with Closure***  Instead of function with returning value.

Please refer following code

```
var docRefF : DocumentReference!
func getTime(_ then:(_ first:Int, _ second:Int)->()){
    var FHour = Int()
    var FMinute = Int()


    docRefF = Firestore.firestore().document("sampleTime/worktime")
    dataListener =  docRefF.addSnapshotListener { (docSnapshot, error) in
     guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else { return }
   let data = docSnapshot.data()
    let Hour:Int = data["Hour"]! as! Int
    let Minute: Int = data["Minute"]! as! Int

        FHour = Hour
        FMinute = Minute

    //TODO:- Use other firebase related task same as your code, so that uncomment other lines same as your origional

    then(FHour, FMinute) // This is closure call back line

     }
   }

   //Calling your function
    getTime { (first, second) in

    print(first,second)

    }
```